# How to change class Library name permantently?

Tags: c#

I am programming with C# to write a service,and my class library original name begin like :Common.

And this name was conflict to another dynamic link library:`common.logging.dll`.

And i change it,but when i reference it to another library,it is also conflict.Although i change the name to:`jsptpd.commom`.

This is the conflict code:

```
private static readonly Common.Logging.ILog logger = Common.Logging.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

And it is name showing in the program name,but when i reference and enter common in class,it also tips the old name,not the common.logging.

How to solved?

Conflict:

When i referece the Common.Logging.dll and the jsptpd.CommonImpl(the old name is common).dll.

The program tips:

```
Namespace jsptpd.common not exists type or namespace "logging",do you lack of dll or reference?
```

But when i am not reference `jsptpd.CommonImpl(the old name is common).dll` the logging can correct:

```
Common.Logging.ILog.
```

Comment: Please explain "conflict".

Comment: I am not sure about what you are asking, but perhaps you can benefit from creating an alias for a type as explained in [using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

Comment: Sounds to me that you are confusing the assembly name with the namespace name.  It is the namespace name that matters here.  Go back to that project and just pick a better name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understood your problem.

Basically you have two assembly that are called Common.Something1, and Common.Something2. And when you use classes from Common.Something1, you get an error because he assumes that you are in Common.Something2.

If your problem is this one, it's simple to solve.

In the using area of the class you can define the using with an alias.

```
using CommonNamespace1 = Common.Something1;
using CommonNamespace2 = Common.Something2;
```

and in the rest of the code, you declare like

```
private static readonly CommonNamespace1.Logging.ILog logger = CommonNamespace1.Logging.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

If this isn't your problem, please detail more.